# What does the UML symbol with a cross inside a circle mean?

Tags: uml

I've been trying to figure out what this certain UML symbol means.

---

[image: Seems to be called "containment" in visual paradigm]

---

It is only used in design diagrams (as far as I know). 
I've got [UML distilled (3<sup>rd</sup>  edition)](http://docenti.unicam.it/tmp/1704.pdf), but that too doesn't explain what this is.
Searching around the web gave me some meager results as well.

Does anyone know what this particular association is?

Comment: What diagram type is this on?

Comment: Design diagram, stupid of me not to add that to the topic.

Comment: I use Visual Paradigm, but I don't know what this "design diagram" is. You mention UML. Is it a class diagram? Object diagram? Something else?

Comment: Sorry, it's a class diagram. We were taught to call it design since it is the next step after an analysis diagram

Comment: Since you found an answer, I probably won't dig deeper. However, you should post the answer as an answer and not an edit to the question. Self-answering is acceptable and recommended for situations like this!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After searching for something completely irrelevant (Googled `"uml triangle"`), I stumbled upon this:

[image]

while meaning to find something like this, which is an Association Pointer:

[image: Association pointer]

In obsolete UML 1.4.2, a declaring class and a nested class may be shown connected by a line with an "anchor" icon on the end (a cross inside a circle) connected to a declaring class (namespace).